# Concatenación de String. Error al comparar cadenas

Tags: java, array, poo, class

Ante todo, Feliz año nuevo a todo el mundo. Espero que hayáis pasado una feliz nochevieja con los vuestros y que estéis todos bien de saludo.

Al grano. Tengo un método para llenar un ListArray con 50 elementos con datos "aleatorios" para probar cosas del ListArray. Me pasa una cosa muy curiosa. Este es el código del método que he implementado:

```
public void llenarArray () {               // Método llenarArray para probar cosas con datos predeterminados.

    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i ++) {
        
        aux = new Vehiculo();
        
        int digitosMatricula = 1234 + i;
        String letrasMatricula = "AAA";
        
        String matriculaTemporal = String.valueOf(digitosMatricula) + letrasMatricula;
    
        aux.setMarca("Prueba " + (1 + i));
        aux.setMatricula(matriculaTemporal);
        aux.setNumKms(1 + i);
        aux.setFechaMatriculacion(LocalDate.now());
        aux.setDescripcion("Rojo");
        aux.setPrecio(2000 + i);
        aux.setNombrePropietario("David Pozo Catalina");
        aux.setDniPropietario("71949635T");
    
        coche.add(aux);
        
    }           // FIN DE BUCLE FOR.

}       // FIN DEL MÉTODO llenarArray.
```

En los 50 elementos creados, crea matrículas consecutivas, p.e 1235AAA, 1236AAA... La cosa es que tengo otro método para buscar vehículo por matrícula:

```
public String buscaVehiculo (String matricula) {            // Método para buscar vehículos en el ArrayList Vehiculo pasando una matrícula.
    
    String datosVehiculo = "";                  // Variable de tipo String donde se almacenarán los datos del vehículo buscado.
    String auxMatricula = matricula;            // Variable de tipo String donde se almacenará la matrícula pedida por el usuario para buscar.
    
    for (int i = 0; i < coche.size(); i ++) {
        
        if (coche.get(i).getMatricula().equalsIgnoreCase(auxMatricula)) {
            datosVehiculo = "COCHE Nº " + (i + 1) + "\n" + "\nMarca: " + coche.get(i).getMarca() + "\nMatrícula: " + coche.get(i).getMatricula()
                + "\nKilómetros: " + coche.get(i).getNumKms() + "\nFecha de Matriculación: " + coche.get(i).getFechaMatriculacion() + "\nDescripción: " +
                coche.get(i).getDescripcion() + "\nPrecio: " + coche.get(i).getPrecio() + "€" + "\nPropietario: " + coche.get(i).getNombrePropietario() +
                "\nDNI Propietario: " + coche.get(i).getDniPropietario();
        } else {
            datosVehiculo = "Esa matrícula no existe.";
        }
    }

    return datosVehiculo;
    
}       // FIN DEL MÉTODO buscaVehiculo.
```

Y el resultado al comparar la matrícula pedida en el método buscaVehiculo con una de las 50 almacenadas es: "Esa matrícula no existe".

Pero cuando meto uno a uno los datos del vehículo con un JOptionPane.showInputDialog, el método buscaVehiculo SÍ QUE FUNCIONA. Y no se cual puede ser la razón porque escupo por consola alguna matrícula generada por el método llenarArray y luego la escribo tal como aparece en el método buscaVehiculo y no me encuentra el vehículo. Pero tengo otro método que se llama listaVehiculo que me saca por pantalla el contenido del ListArray y SÍ QUE APARECE.

No entiendo que ocurre.

Un saludo y gracias.

Comment: Pues pasa que nunca interrumpes tu bucle, así que en realidad por mucho que busques todas las matrículas, la única que importa es la última. Dentro del `if` cuando las matrículas coinciden, en vez de asignar el string usa un `return` para detener el bucle... porque si la encuentras pero luego la siguiente ya no coincide, lo único que vas a ver es "Esa matrícula no existe", porque has machacado la matrícula que si encontraste

Comment: Muchas gracias. He puesto un break; y parece funcionar. Un abrazo y feliz año